# Rails - session[:user_id] is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While using rails 4.0.0 I'm trying to store the session user id in the db but I'm having some issues. 
I tried:
`@active_user = session[:user_id]` - I'm getting a nil response. 
`@active_user = request.session_options[:id]` - Weird behavior, the first time I load the page I'm getting a nil response. the 2nd load generates the user_id.

Ideas?

Comment: Was it working before in rails 3? Could you give the code for the sessions controller / login process?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as i need more code, but are you pushing your user_id in session? And why are you using session anyways, i mean when you can do something like this:

```
@active_user = current_user.id
```

Its neat and clean as well